# Multiplying Arrays - Array Math

Tags: arrays, math, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have 2 arrays I want to do mathematical manipulation on.  Do I need to loop through each value of the arrays or can I do the calculation in one step in bulk.

Ex: Array1(0,5,3)  Array2(1,4,3)

Array3 = Array1*Array2 = (0*1, 4*5, 3*3) = (0,20,9)
Array3 = Array1+Array2 = (0+1,4+5,3+3) = (1,9,6)

Does the matrix math like determinants, etc apply or is it completely different?

Comment: Welcome!
Which programming language would you like to use? - put in tags.
In your `Array3`, if the first element is `0 * 1`, the second should be `5 * 4`...

Comment: In JavaScript: `Array3 = Array1.map((currentValue, index) => currentValue * Array2[index])`.
Or, loop with `for`...

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to my mind in C# :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN8ef.png)

Comment: The first element is (0*1) and second is 5*4.  I was working with excel vba which has serious limitiations it seems.  I guess C# is the second best language.  I wanted to do this without looping, just one statement like vector math.